# react native stackNavigator create 2 navigation in nested navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

i use the createStackNavigator in react native and when i'm using the navigator inside of navigator i face with multiple screen and view issue.

expected to see only one navigator - shown in image :
attached image for batter understand :
[image: issue-img]

and the code i using is :

```
import React from "react";
import { SettingsScreen } from "../../features/settings/screens/settings.screen";
import { FavouritesScreen } from "../../features/settings/screens/favourites.screen";

import {
  createStackNavigator,
  CardStyleInterpolators,
} from "@react-navigation/stack";

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();

export const SettingsNavigator = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator
      headerMode="screen"
      screenOptions={{
        cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
      }}
    >
      <SettingsStack.Screen
        options={{
          header: () => null,
        }}
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
      />

      <SettingsStack.Screen
        name="Favourites"
        component={FavouritesScreen}
      />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your settings screen to hide header through the props options. Just set headerShown to false like this

```
  <SettingsStack.Screen
    options={{
       headerShown: false,
    }}
    name="Settings"
    component={SettingsScreen}
  />
```